# Adding Buffer Wizard function in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, buffer

[image: ]]I am trying to clip a series of raster grids to include into a mosaic.

Presently I have made a model that initially reclassifies a grid into one class and then converts raster to polygon to get a boundary file for that particular raster.  I have used Buffer Wizard to generate an internal buffer setting the buffer width to 25m.  I can then use this output to erase against the original boundary feature class, which I will use to clip/mask the raster.

I cannot however utilise the Buffer Wizard tool directly in ModelBuilder. I have seen in other posts that you could potentially use an iterate but I am not familiar with them and cannot seem to get it to work.

I have approx ~550 images to process like this so do not want to do it manually if I can help it.

So the thumbnails graphically displays the process with the clipped raster being what I wanted, and the process in ModelBuilder in the schematic with the Buffer Wizard performed in the data view interface of ArcMap

Comment: And you're doing so using... AutoCAD?

Comment: Could you share some pictures of the input and the desired output?

Comment: Why not use the buffer tool instead of the wizard?

Comment: Does the buffer tool do an internal buffer without rounded corners?